# JBoss EAP 6.4.21 returns "400 Bad Request"

Tags: jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7, jboss-web

JBoss EAP 6.4.21  returns "400 Bad Request" 
response when sending unescaped characters (raw characters like | ) in the query string and path parameters of the request.

Below setup has been tried in `<system-properties>` in domain.

```
<property name="-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
<property name="-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your JBoss version and the [RedHat Official Site](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3181201):

> The fix for CVE-2016-6816 enforces rules more strictly when handling invalid characters in HTTP requests.
>
> As a result any clients making requests containing any of the following ASCII characters will receive a 400:
>
> 1. Control characters (values 0x01 to 0x1f, and 0x7f)
> 2. 8-bit ASCII values (values > 0x7f)
> 3. Any of the following characters:
>      ' ' (space character)
>      '"' (double quote)
>      '#' (hash or pound)
>      '<' (less than)
>      '>' (greater than)
>      '\' (back slash)
>      '^' (circumflex)
>      '`' (backquote)
>      '{' (left squiggly bracket or brace)
>      '|' (vertical bar)
>      '}' (right squiggly bracket or brace)

### **In summary:**

For your jboss version you have to add this line in your startup script `standalone.sh`

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dtomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow='{|}'"
```

Take in mind that if you upgrade to eap 7.1.1+, this solution won't work. Instead add this line to the `standalone.conf` file:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.wildfly.undertow.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL=true"
```

I hope this can help you.